# Select the set of <li> elements that come before the one with the "active" class and not that come after

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I want to select the set of `<li>` elements that come before the one with the "active" class and not that are come after "active" class.

```
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>

<li class="active"></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's how you can select all the elements above the class `active` in CSS and JS

FOR your css:

```
li:not(.active):not(li.active ~ li) {
    /*you style*/
}
```

For your JavaScript:

```
const elementsAboveActive = document.querySelectorAll('li:not(.active):not(li.active ~ li)');
// for example
elementsAboveActive.forEach((i) => i.style.color = 'aqua');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelectorAll()` to select all the `<li>` elements into a list. Then `filter()` that list, searching for the one which is active. Once you find it, set a flag and ignore the rest of the `<li>` elements.

```js
let foundIt = false;
let elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('li')];
let first = elements.filter(function(e) {
    if ( e.classList.contains('active') ) {
        foundIt = true;
    }

    return ! foundIt
})

console.log(first) // The elements before the "active" one
```

```html
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>

<li class="active"></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
```